# Array.indexOf() not finding the value when passing string as a variable?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google script to extend a Google Spreadsheet. I'm trying to make a function that will determine the index of a given column by passing its header in the function.

```
function columnIndexForHeader(header) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var headers = data[0]
  var index = data.indexOf(header) + 1
  Logger.log("Looking for header "+header)
  Logger.log("List of headers: "+headers)
  Logger.log("Header 12: "+headers[12])
  Logger.log("Index of History:"+headers.indexOf("History"))
  Logger.log("Requested index for header "+header+" is "+ index)
  return index
}
```

In the example above, I am looking for a column header called History, currently the 13th column in the spreadsheet (hence index 12 in the array).

When I call up the function I use e.g.:

```
currentSheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndexForHeader("History")).setValue("New")
```

Now searching the header index in the with a string (as with the logger example) works fine, but for some reason it is not able to to find the header when searching with the variable (returning -1 to indexOf(). The log will show the following:

```
[14-06-28 22:30:37:665 ICT] Looking for header History
[14-06-28 22:30:37:702 ICT] List of headers: ID,First-Last,Nick,Course,Section,Grade,Correspondence,Remarks,Attendence,Status,Program,Major,History,Nationality,LEP ID,Email (Stamford),Email (Private),Phone,
[14-06-28 22:30:37:703 ICT] Header 12:History
[14-06-28 22:30:37:703 ICT] Index of History:12
[14-06-28 22:30:37:703 ICT] Requested index for header History is 0
```

Why is it failing to find the header from a variable, whilst it seems to be successful when passing a string?

Comment: You do `data.indexOf` rather than `headers.indexOf`.

Comment: Doh! (I've been looking at this for 2h now and didn't see it) :O Thanks for lending your hawk's eyesight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot an array index,

```
var headers = data[0];
var index = data[0].indexOf(header) + 1; // not data, data[0]!
```

Or,

```
var index = headers.indexOf(header) + 1; // using the variable from the previous line.
```